# Electron JS ReCaptcha Harvester

Tags: javascript, request, electron, recaptcha, intercept

I need to make a recaptcha V2 harvester in Electron JS. I tried the following code but all I get it "ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key". I think I need to intercept requests. Someone suggested me to use "interceptBufferProtocol" method in JS but I don't know how to use that. Can someone help me ?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Captcha Harvester</title>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/submit" method="POST">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" id="captchaFrame" data-sitekey="actual-site-key" data-callback="sub"></div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to "Domain mismatching".
Please set the domain of target site.
Generally, following method is used for harvesting captchas.

- Open Webdriver.
- Set the domain of target site.
- Inject harvesting code